# Ubuntu 13.04 only sometimes starts: "no System-disk or disk error"

Tags: 13.04, grub2, laptop, startup, hp

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my HP 2530p Laptop with no other OS installed. 
All worked well but when restarting, after the BIOS screen, there was just a blank black screen reading "no system-disk or disk error".

Restarting multiple times, Ubuntu started normally. But upon the next restart, the same happened: "no system-disk or disk error" and I needed to repeat this procedure.

According to the "disk"-utility, my disk (Toshiba, 120 GB) is 47 Celcius degrees warm and has no disk errors.

Is this a Ubuntu-problem or a Grub-Problem (no Grub menue pops up because there is no choice at the start)?

Comment: No sound more like hardware to me. Like a loose cable.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your boot device (hard disk drive, or CD-ROM drive) does not contain boot files.  To resolve this issue, try one of these, and then restart your computer:

- Remove any CD/DVD from the optical drive
- Change your computer's boot sequence, to boot from the bootable
  device. (this is done from the system BIOS)
- Make sure an OS is installed on the hard drive.

If non of these work,  may have a hardware problem with your hard drive.  Go to the Toshiba website, and see if they have a bootable tool to test the drive with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to add a comment and this is not a complete answer, but I have the same problem with my ASUS KJ52. With me it helps to change the root paramater in grub from UUID to the real name of the root partition, say /dev/sda3. Also there's no problem booting Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in installing ubuntu 18.04 on a new SSD disk without any other OS. Installation was complete successfully but after a restart, I had encountered this error.
This problem was solved by connecting the SSD disk SATA cable to the SATA0 socket on the motherboard. This affects determining master/slave disk apparently.